# Remove despite "Device or resource busy" on a GitHub Actions Windows worker

Tags: windows, powershell, gradle, caching, github-actions

I would like to cleanup the gradle cache before storing it on GitHub actions. The current relevant configuration is the following:

```yaml
      - name: Turn off the Gradle Daemon
        shell: bash
        run: ./gradlew --stop
      - name: Cleanup Gradle Cache
        shell: bash
        run: |
          rm -f ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
          rm -f ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/gc.properties
```

The process works perfectly under Linux and MacOS X, but on windows, despite stopping the Gradle Daemon before running the cleanup, I get the following error:

```
Run rm -f ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
rm: cannot remove '/c/Users/runneradmin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock': Device or resource busy
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Is there any way to **force** the removal of a file? I don't care about inconsistencies, I want that file removed, that's it.
The removal must be performed in a continuos integration environment, so no graphical tools, just Powershell or git bash.

Comment: Did you try PowerShell with `Remove-Item -Force`?

Comment: This one seems to work! Thanks

Comment: Your welcome! I make it an actual answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok about using PowerShell instead of Bash, you could use it like you would with Bash:

```
Remove-Item -Force
```

`-Force` is not the same as `-f` of bash's `rm` ([reference](https://superuser.com/a/1450727)), but it should be OK for your problem: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) states that

> `-Force` Forces the cmdlet to remove items that cannot otherwise be changed, such as hidden or read-only files or read-only aliases or variables.